# Why does Privacy Badger block Firebase javascript files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase, privacy

It appears that if the Privacy Badger chrome extension from the EFF is installed, then it blocks Firebase on the client.

Specifically these two scripts get blocked by the client:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/reactfire/0.4.0/reactfire.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to get Firebase to work with client browsers that want to protect their privacy with Privacy Badger (https://www.eff.org/privacybadger)

Answer (score 1):

It's just another extension that blocks all external links, like AdBlock or uBlock do.

You can ask that PrivacyBadger's developers to whitelist the script or, if they just use a common list like EasyPrivacy, contact the maintainers of the list.

Or embed the script files in your extension as you probably update it periodically anyway.